# How to cast a Field as a Set class in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

If a field is a `Set<String>` how to determine the type of generic from the `Set`(in this case `String`)?

I have this method that determines the generic type:

```
private boolean isSetTypeOf( Set<?> set, Class<?> clazz )
{
    for ( Object object : set )
    {
        if ( object.getClass().equals( clazz ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I cannot cast Field as a Set, thus cannot use this method.

```
Field field = getTheField();

if ( ReflectionUtils.isType( field, Set.class )
{
    // Error
    if ( isSetTypeOf( field, clazz ) )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Basically I know that the field type is a Set, now I need to know the type of object that the set holds and only after that I will use that field.

Comment: Your method is currently just checking whether *any* elements of the set are the right type. That doesn't tell you anything about the rest of the elements, or whether the set could change later.

Comment: Do you want to check the parameterized type of a generic type in your class? Currently you are checking the actual type stored in the `Set`.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post. Filed is of type Field(I'm using reflection).

Comment: Do you know the variable name of the `Set` type field? Can we assume, you get the appropriate field?

Comment: Yes, the field is correct. The error is at compiling. I do not know how to force field to be of Set for the isSetTypeOf method since he is a Set in reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have got the appropriate `Field` type corresponding to your `Set` type field in your class, you can use the following code to find out the type of *Parameterized Type*:

```
Type type = field.getGenericType();   // Get the generic type of the Field, 

if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    System.out.println("Parameterized type for : " + type);

    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    Type[] types = pType.getActualTypeArguments();

    for (Type aType: types) {
        System.out.println(aType);
    }
}
```

For `Set<String>` type field, this will output:

```
Parameterized type for : java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
class java.lang.String
```

Using `isSetTypeOf` method will not give you the parameterized type, but the actual type of the elements stored in the `Set`.

Comment: Nice. I've learnt something today. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this `object.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)`

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
if ( isSetTypeOf( new HashSet().add(field), clazz ) )
```

instead of:

```
if ( isSetTypeOf( field, clazz ) )
```